# Включения микрофона в popup окне

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. 
Столкнусля со следующей проблемой: необходимо создать плагтн для хрома для VoIP. Проблема в том что не могу разрешить доступ к микрофону. Перелопатил гугл - ничего не нашел. Возможно ли вообще при откритой попап странице отобразить запрос на разрешения использования микрофона или автоматически разрешать на фотовой странице?